# Clear Run Prompt - Awesome WM Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, awesome-wm

I use the Awesome Window Manger in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have built up a messy run prompt (<kbd>Meta/Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>) history due to loads of misspellings.

Does anyone know how I could clear the history or even clear individual items in the Run Prompt history (I tend to scroll through the list and select misspelled commands quite often)

Thanks

Comment: Can you hover your mouse over the item and press `delete`?

Comment: @Burgi - Hovering the mouse over the run prompt and pressing delete does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in the end. You can view you Awesome WM history in `.cache/awesome/history` - I was able to remove my typo's and have a cleaner history